# Traveling with laptop without iPhoto, How do I acquire older version like 8.1.2?

Tags: photos.app

Traveling with Macbook running 10.6 (recent upgrade from 10.5.8). It was a gift and does not have iPhoto. My Sony camera is jammed with images I would ordinarily unload to the big iMac at home (which has iPhoto). Without upgrading to the latest OS (which seems problematic) is there someplace I can acquire (buy, beg, borrow) an older version of iPhoto such as 8.1.2? The Apple site itself has some very unhappy reports from users of the new iPhoto. Upgrading this entire laptop to the latest OS just so I can download some images seems excessive. Or am I wimping out here?

Answer (score 1):

You say the camera is jammed, do you just need to move to make space on the camera?

Most logical answer is to buy a new card for the camera... or connect the camera, use the USB features to move the photos off.  You will still have them when you back home to use on the big iMac at home.

However, if you want the version just download 8.1.2.
http://support.apple.com/kb/DL970

Comment: That link is to a 13.MB updater, not much use without the actual app...

Answer (score 0):

You don't *need* iPhoto to get the shots off the camera. You can do this with Image Capture (in your Applications Folder) and simply store them in folders until you get home.  You can't download iPhoto v8 - at least not legally - and the only way to install it is to purchase an iLife 09 disk.